# How can I force my table width into the width of my container?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table:

[image]

Here is how I created it : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/axza8xs1/)

I've tried this in my CSS :

```
table{
    width:100%;
}
```

```css
td span {

    float:right;

    width:20%;

    text-align:center;

}

td {

    text-align: center;

}

td:nth-child(1) {

    text-align: left;

}

th {

    text-align: center;

    background-color: black;

    color: white;

}

.progress_type2 .progressbar {

    height: 16px;

    border-radius: 10px;

}

.progress_type2 .progressbar.colorblue {

    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #5e91b7, 0 -1px 0 #5e91b7, 1px 0 0 #5e91b7, -1px 0 0 #5e91b7, inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);

}

.progress_type2 .progressbar.colorgreen {

    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #699847, 0 -1px 0 #699847, 1px 0 0 #699847, -1px 0 0 #699847, inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);

}

.progress_type2 .progressbar.colororange {

    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #a27132, 0 -1px 0 #a27132, 1px 0 0 #a27132, -1px 0 0 #a27132, inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);

}

.progress_type2 .progressbar.colorpink {

    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #7b3b65, 0 -1px 0 #7b3b65, 1px 0 0 #7b3b65, -1px 0 0 #7b3b65, inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);

}

.progress_type2 .progressbar.colorgrey {

    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #747474, 0 -1px 0 #747474, 1px 0 0 #747474, -1px 0 0 #747474, inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);

}

.progress_type2 .progressbar.colorred {

    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #7b3b65, 0 -1px 0 #7b3b65, 1px 0 0 #7b3b65, -1px 0 0 #7b3b65, inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);

}

/* These classes are used by Types 1-7 */

.colorblue {

    background: #8cd7f7;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8cd7f7 0%, #56bff3 100%);

    /* Firefox 3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8cd7f7 0%, #56bff3 100%);

    /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8cd7f7 0%, #56bff3 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8cd7f7 0%, #56bff3 100%);

    /* IE 10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(top, #8cd7f7 0%, #56bff3 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8cd7f7', endColorstr='#56bff3', GradientType=0);

    /* IE6-9 */

}

.colorgreen {

    background: #b0ea77;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b0ea77 0%, #80de49 100%);

    /* Firefox 3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b0ea77 0%, #80de49 100%);

    /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b0ea77 0%, #80de49 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b0ea77 0%, #80de49 100%);

    /* IE 10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(top, #b0ea77 0%, #80de49 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8cd7f7', endColorstr='#80de49', GradientType=0);

    /* IE6-9 */

}

.colororange {

    background: #ffb62c;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffb62c 0%, #ff8a1c 100%);

    /* Firefox 3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffb62c 0%, #ff8a1c 100%);

    /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffb62c 0%, #ff8a1c 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffb62c 0%, #ff8a1c 100%);

    /* IE 10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffb62c 0%, #ff8a1c 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffb62c', endColorstr='#ff8a1c', GradientType=0);

    /* IE6-9 */

}

.colorpink {

    background: #e578be;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e578be 0%, #d54a96 100%);

    /* Firefox 3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e578be 0%, #d54a96 100%);

    /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e578be 0%, #d54a96 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e578be 0%, #d54a96 100%);

    /* IE 10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(top, #e578be 0%, #d54a96 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e578be', endColorstr='#d54a96', GradientType=0);

    /* IE6-9 */

}

.colorred {

    background: #db2713;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #db2713 0%, #d54a4a 100%);

    /* Firefox 3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #db2713 0%, #d54a4a 100%);

    /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #db2713 0%, #d54a4a 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #db2713 0%, #d54a4a 100%);

    /* IE 10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(top, #db2713 0%, #d54a4a 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#db2713', endColorstr='#d54a4a', GradientType=0);

    /* IE6-9 */

}

.colorgrey {

    background: #cbcbcb;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cbcbcb 0%, #ababab 100%);

    /* Firefox 3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cbcbcb 0%, #ababab 100%);

    /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cbcbcb 0%, #ababab 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cbcbcb 0%, #ababab 100%);

    /* IE 10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(top, #cbcbcb 0%, #ababab 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cbcbcb', endColorstr='#ababab', GradientType=0);

    /* IE6-9 */

}

.width_0 {

    width: 0% !important;

}

.width_10 {

    width: 10% !important;

}

.width_20 {

    width: 20% !important;

}

.width_30 {

    width: 30% !important;

}

.width_40 {

    width: 40% !important;

}

.width_50 {

    width: 50% !important;

}

.width_60 {

    width: 60% !important;

}

.width_70 {

    width: 70% !important;

}

.width_80 {

    width: 80% !important;

}

.width_90 {

    width: 90% !important;

}

.width_100 {

    width: 100% !important;

}

.width_1 {

    width: 1% !important;

}

.width_11 {

    width: 11% !important;

}

.width_21 {

    width: 21% !important;

}

.width_31 {

    width: 31% !important;

}

.width_41 {

    width: 41% !important;

}

.width_51 {

    width: 51% !important;

}

.width_61 {

    width: 61% !important;

}

.width_71 {

    width: 71% !important;

}

.width_81 {

    width: 81% !important;

}

.width_91 {

    width: 91% !important;

}

.width_2 {

    width: 2% !important;

}

.width_12 {

    width: 12% !important;

}

.width_22 {

    width: 22% !important;

}

.width_32 {

    width: 32% !important;

}

.width_42 {

    width: 42% !important;

}

.width_52 {

    width: 52% !important;

}

.width_62 {

    width: 62% !important;

}

.width_72 {

    width: 72% !important;

}

.width_82 {

    width: 82% !important;

}

.width_92 {

    width: 92% !important;

}

.width_3 {

    width: 3% !important;

}

.width_13 {

    width: 13% !important;

}

.width_23 {

    width: 23% !important;

}

.width_33 {

    width: 33% !important;

}

.width_43 {

    width: 43% !important;

}

.width_53 {

    width: 53% !important;

}

.width_63 {

    width: 63% !important;

}

.width_73 {

    width: 73% !important;

}

.width_83 {

    width: 83% !important;

}

.width_93 {

    width: 93% !important;

}

.width_4 {

    width: 4% !important;

}

.width_14 {

    width: 14% !important;

}

.width_24 {

    width: 24% !important;

}

.width_34 {

    width: 34% !important;

}

.width_44 {

    width: 44% !important;

}

.width_54 {

    width: 54% !important;

}

.width_64 {

    width: 64% !important;

}

.width_74 {

    width: 74% !important;

}

.width_84 {

    width: 84% !important;

}

.width_94 {

    width: 94% !important;

}

.width_5 {

    width: 5% !important;

}

.width_15 {

    width: 15% !important;

}

.width_25 {

    width: 25% !important;

}

.width_35 {

    width: 35% !important;

}

.width_45 {

    width: 45% !important;

}

.width_55 {

    width: 55% !important;

}

.width_65 {

    width: 65% !important;

}

.width_75 {

    width: 75% !important;

}

.width_85 {

    width: 85% !important;

}

.width_95 {

    width: 95% !important;

}

.width_6 {

    width: 6% !important;

}

.width_16 {

    width: 16% !important;

}

.width_26 {

    width: 26% !important;

}

.width_36 {

    width: 36% !important;

}

.width_46 {

    width: 46% !important;

}

.width_66 {

    width: 66% !important;

}

.width_66 {

    width: 66% !important;

}

.width_76 {

    width: 76% !important;

}

.width_86 {

    width: 86% !important;

}

.width_96 {

    width: 96% !important;

}

.width_7 {

    width: 7% !important;

}

.width_17 {

    width: 17% !important;

}

.width_27 {

    width: 27% !important;

}

.width_37 {

    width: 37% !important;

}

.width_47 {

    width: 47% !important;

}

.width_57 {

    width: 57% !important;

}

.width_67 {

    width: 67% !important;

}

.width_77 {

    width: 77% !important;

}

.width_87 {

    width: 87% !important;

}

.width_97 {

    width: 97% !important;

}

.width_8 {

    width: 8% !important;

}

.width_18 {

    width: 18% !important;

}

.width_28 {

    width: 28% !important;

}

.width_38 {

    width: 38% !important;

}

.width_48 {

    width: 48% !important;

}

.width_58 {

    width: 58% !important;

}

.width_68 {

    width: 68% !important;

}

.width_78 {

    width: 78% !important;

}

.width_88 {

    width: 88% !important;

}

.width_98 {

    width: 98% !important;

}

.width_9 {

    width: 9% !important;

}

.width_19 {

    width: 19% !important;

}

.width_29 {

    width: 29% !important;

}

.width_39 {

    width: 39% !important;

}

.width_49 {

    width: 49% !important;

}

.width_59 {

    width: 59% !important;

}

.width_69 {

    width: 69% !important;

}

.width_79 {

    width: 79% !important;

}

.width_89 {

    width: 89% !important;

}

.width_99 {

    width: 99% !important;

}

<style type="text/css">[dir='rtl'] .slick-next {

    right: auto;

    left: -25px;

}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev {

    right: -25px;

    left: auto;

}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before {

    font-family: FontAwesome;

    color: black;

    content:"\f137";

}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before {

    font-family: FontAwesome;

    color: black;

    content:"\f138";

}

.slick-next {

    right: 10px;

}

.slick-prev {

    left: 250px;

}

.slick-next:before {

    font-family: FontAwesome;

    color: black;

    content:"\f138";

}

.slick-prev:before {

    font-family: FontAwesome;

    color: black;

    content:"\f137";

}

.progress_type2 {

    height: 16px;

    padding: 1px;

    background: #ddd;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .6), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);

    border-radius: 10px;

    width:80%;

    float:left;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<body style="background-color:#333333;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:white;">
        <br>
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead class="text-center ">
                <th width="300">Objective</th>
                <th width="300">Mastery</th>
                <th width="100">Standards</th>
                <th width="160">Remediation</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>Use the distribute Property to produce equivalent</td>
                    <td>
                        <div width="270" class="progress_type2">
                            <div class="progressbar colorgreen width_95"></div>
                        </div><span width="30">95%</span>

                    </td>
                    <td>6.EE.3 &nbsp; 6.EE.4</td>
                    <td>www.bigideamath.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Apply properties of operations to add and substract linear expressions</td>
                    <td>
                        <div width="270" class="progress_type2">
                            <div class="progressbar colorgreen width_80"></div>
                        </div><span width="30">80%</span>

                    </td>
                    <td>6.EE.3 &nbsp; 6.EE.4</td>
                    <td>www.bigideamath.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Apply properties of operations to simply algebraic expressions</td>
                    <td>
                        <div width="270" class="progress_type2">
                            <div class="progressbar colorgreen width_95"></div>
                        </div><span width="30">95%</span>

                    </td>
                    <td>6.EE.3 &nbsp; 6.EE.4</td>
                    <td>www.bigideamath.com</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: For someone that downvote my question, please kindly explain what did I do wrong so I can learn ?

Comment: deleted. And wasnt me who downvoted. I do not downvote questions no matter how low quality a question is because I remember my early days where I struggled with basic code myself lol

Comment: Probably due to the fact that you say "It doesn't seem to work." without any indication of what doesn't work. See [ask] for information about what makes a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table's padding was causing the space around the container . By removing the padding the table was then flush with the container. The table also had a margin bottom which again , created a space between the table and the container..

```
.container {
   padding:0;
}
.table{
   margin-bottom:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/axza8xs1/5/

Comment: Please explain that this code do, it may help future visitors. Without explanation this is just a random code.

Answer (score 0):

removing the class `container` seems to help ;)

you are using a boostrap ("container") class which does exactly what you **don't** want to happen, so why are you using it?

Comment: My fault, I am confuse between the page width and the container width. I mean container width. I update my question title. Please update your answer, I will make sure to accept it. Since you're the first one that answer it.  Again. I appologize.

Comment: well, you must set the padding on this specific `container` to `0`...either via CSS by adding some extra class to it like `no-padding` or something, or directly on the element using a `style` attribute. then the table will "fill" it up

Comment: yeah you can just inspect the `container` using firebug (or any other browser DOM inspector) and immediately see which element is causing the gap. in this case the first element in the chain was the container itself which has padding inherited to it via bootstrap

Comment: @rangerover.js - you did make a promise in your fist comment, what happened to it?